# Python: ImportError: cannot import module for user excepr for root

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I installed a modue like this:

```
# pip3 install mega
```

And everything works fine. If I try to import from this module as root user, works OK:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mega import Mega
>>> mega = Mega()
>>> quit()
```

But if I try to do the same thing with a regular user, it doesn't work:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mega import Mega
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mega' from 'mega' (unknown location)
>>>
```

This happens with all non root users. Checking the PYTHONPATH, seems to be the same for root and for unprivileged users:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
... 

/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
>>>
```

I'm running Raspbian 10 on a Raspberry Pi 3b+

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was a matter of permissions. I don't know why, pip3 installs the module with no permission but for root user. A simple bash script corrects the issue:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read line; do
    sudo chmod -R a+rx $line
done
```

Now it works like a charm.